# Who wrote the kinnah that contrasts leaving Egypt and leaving Jerusalem?

Tags: song-poetry, tisha-bav, authorship

In most collections of kinnot that are read on Tisha b'Av, there is one titled אש תוקד בקרבי ([text](http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/286.html), [text](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93_%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99), and [English translation](http://opensiddur.org/prayers-for/special-days/commemorative-days/fast-days/tisha-bav/esh-tukad-bkirbi-a-fire-shall-burn-within-me-translated-by-gabriel-seed/)) that poetically contrasts the joy we felt when being liberated from Egypt with the misery we felt when being exiled from Jerusalem.

Does anyone know who authored this particular kinnah?  If it is not certain, are there any scholarly conjectures?

Comment: According to Artscroll the kinnah is of unknown authorship.

Comment: @user6591 Accd to the link in this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44256/759 it's by Ibn Ezra

Comment: Interesting. (15 char)

Comment: @DoubleAA This question, too. `:-)`